I am using faceapi.js for real time face detection but getting error
I am using faceapi.js in react like this
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Center,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  Heading,
  useToast,
  ChakraProvider,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
import './Signup.css';

const StudentSignup: React.FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [rollNo, setRollNo] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState('');
  const [program, setProgram] = useState('');
  const [batch, setBatch] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [faceEmbedding, setFaceEmbedding] = useState<number[] | null>(null);
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [isCapturing, setIsCapturing] = useState(false);
  const [permissionGranted, setPermissionGranted] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const toast = useToast();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadModelsAndDetectFace = async () => {
      const MODEL_URL = '/models';
      try {
        // Load all models
        await Promise.all([
          faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
          faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
          faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
        ]).then(async () => {
          // Once all models are loaded, perform face detection
          if (videoRef.current) {
            const detection = await faceapi
              .detectSingleFace(videoRef.current)
              .withFaceLandmarks()
              .withFaceDescriptor();
            if (detection) {
              setFaceEmbedding(Array.from(detection.descriptor));
              toast({
                title: 'Face Captured',
                description: 'Face embedding captured successfully.',
                status: 'success',
                duration: 3000,
                isClosable: true,
              });
            } else {
              console.log('Failed to capture face');
              toast({
                title: 'Face Capture Failed',
                description: 'Unable to capture face. Please try again.',
                status: 'error',
                duration: 3000,
                isClosable: true,
              });
            }
          } else {
            console.error('Video element not found');
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error loading models or detecting face:', error);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading models or detecting face:', error);
      }
    };
  
    const handlePermission = async () => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        }
        setPermissionGranted(true);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error accessing camera:', err);
        toast({
          title: 'Error',
          description: 'Unable to access camera. Please check your device settings.',
          status: 'error',
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
  
    loadModelsAndDetectFace();
    handlePermission();
  }, [toast]);
  
  const detectFace = async () => {
    if (videoRef.current && canvasRef.current && !isLoading) {
      const detection = await faceapi
        .detectSingleFace(videoRef.current)
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceDescriptor();
  
      if (detection) {
        setFaceEmbedding(Array.from(detection.descriptor));
        toast({
          title: 'Face Captured',
          description: 'Face embedding captured successfully.',
          status: 'success',
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Failed to capture face');
        toast({
          title: 'Face Capture Failed',
          description: 'Unable to capture face. Please try again.',
          status: 'error',
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSignup = async () => {
    if (!name || !email || !rollNo || !age || !program || !batch || !password || !faceEmbedding) {
      console.log('Missing required fields');
      toast({
        title: 'Warning',
        description: 'Please fill in all fields and capture your face.',
        status: 'warning',
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/students/signup',
        { name, email, rollNo, age, program, batch, password, faceEmbedding },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );

      console.log('Signup response:', response.data);

      toast({
        title: 'Signup Successful',
        description: `Welcome, ${name}`,
        status: 'success',
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
      navigate('/studentDashboard');
      // Reset form data
      setName('');
      setEmail('');
      setRollNo('');
      setAge('');
      setProgram('');
      setBatch('');
      setPassword('');
      setFaceEmbedding(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Signup error:', error);

      toast({
        title: 'Signup Failed',
        description: 'There was an error creating your account. Please try again.',
        status: 'error',
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <div className="signup-container">
        <Center h="100vh">
          <Box className="signup-box" p={8} borderWidth={1} borderRadius={8} boxShadow="lg">
            <Heading as="h1" size="xl" mb={6}>
              Student Signup
            </Heading>
            <FormControl id="name" mb={4}>
              <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="text"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="email" mb={4}>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your email"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="rollNo" mb={4}>
                           <FormLabel>Roll Number</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="text"
                value={rollNo}
                onChange={(e) => setRollNo(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your roll number"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="age" mb={4}>
              <FormLabel>Age</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="number"
                value={age}
                onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your age"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="program" mb={4}>
              <FormLabel>Program</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="text"
                value={program}
                onChange={(e) => setProgram(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your program"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="batch" mb={4}>
              <FormLabel>Batch</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="text"
                value={batch}
                onChange={(e) => setBatch(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your batch"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="password" mb={6}>
              <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your password"
              />
            </FormControl>
            {isCapturing ? (
  <>
    <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    <Button colorScheme="blue" size="lg" width="full" onClick={detectFace} mt={4}>
      Capture Face
    </Button>
  </>
) : (
  <Button
    colorScheme="blue"
    size="lg"
    width="full"
    onClick={() => setIsCapturing(true)}
    mt={4}
    disabled={isLoading || !permissionGranted}
  >
    Enroll Face
  </Button>
)}
            <Button colorScheme="blue" size="lg" width="full" onClick={handleSignup} mt={4}>
              Signup
            </Button>
            <Link to="/studentLogin" className="back-link">
              &#8592; Back to Login
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </Center>
      </div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
};

export default StudentSignup;

but whenever i click capture face i get this error
Uncaught (in promise) Error: SsdMobilenetv1 - load model before inference
    at SsdMobilenetv12.forwardInput (face-api__js.js?v=87620118:17446:15)
    at SsdMobilenetv12.<anonymous> (face-api__js.js?v=87620118:17483:25)
    at step (face-api__js.js?v=87620118:13207:19)
    at Object.next (face-api__js.js?v=87620118:13154:14)

i tried many solutions but still getting this error please help me
